# VerticalSlider for Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, user-interface, xamarin.android, material-design

I am using the `Slider` (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/slider/Slider) in a Xamarin.Android app. However, I need a slider that is vertical, and there does not seem to be a VerticalSlider available. Rotating the `Slider` makes it very hard to do layout for anything that is not a fixed size (which is almost everything). Are there any good `View`(s) or relatively simple workarounds available that allow functionality similar to the Slider? I prefer to avoid most third-party downloads for this type of thing, and would prefer that it be a NuGet package if that is my only choice. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box `verticalslider` for you.

I think the common method is set property `Rotation` for the material `Slider`.

You can put the `Slider` into a `Frame`.

Please refer to the following code:

```
        <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
            android:id="@+id/sldPenWidth"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:rotation="270"
            android:value="1"
            android:valueFrom="0.1"
            android:valueTo="10" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried both of those, and although they change the physical motion to vertical, doing the layout is very challenging (including making a custom thumb).

Comment: `doing the layout is very challenging (including making a custom thumb)`  Could you please elaborate on your problem about this?